# p5 - Syntax error: expected ; but got hour

Tags: javascript, syntax-error, p5.js

I have the following code:

```
function setup() {
    createCanvas(500, 500);
    angleMode(DEGREES);
}
function draw() {
    background(0);
    translate(width/2, height/2);
    let hour = hour();
}
```

I get an error on `let hour = hour();` saying that there was supposed to be a **semicolon** there instead of hour. The only way I have found to fix the problem is by writing it as `let; hour = hour();` This gets rid of the error but then the code doesn't run properly. Any ideas?

Comment: how can `hour` define and use itself in the same line?

Comment: @DanielA.White p5 is a javascript library. One of the functions is hour() which gives, well, the hour. My main concern is that I've seen that exact line of code work before.

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, variables and functions can't have the same name. (More confusingly: functions **are** variables!)

So that means that this line:

```
let hour = hour();
```

Is not allowed, because you're trying to reassign the `hour` variable from being a function to being a value. (This is a side effect of using `let`. If you had used `var` then this would have silently did the wrong thing.)

To fix the problem, just rename your variable to something that's not already a function.

```
let myHour = hour();
```

Comment: A great suggestion, but this didn't fix the problem. I've tried variable names "hr" and "myHour" already. Neither of these fix the problem.

Comment: @EternalMonologue Please post a link to a CodePen showing your problem.

Comment: @EternalMonologue I just tried my code and it worked fine.

Comment: [Here](https://codepen.io/missingsemi/project/editor/Apjxra) is the link to the codepen. This doesn't throw an error but it doesn't do anything either. It doesn't even set the background colour.

Comment: Sorry, but that CodePen is not valid. Your .html file is loading from a non-existing libraries directory, and it doesn't link to code.js. Please get into the habit of looking at your [developer tools](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/javascript/developer-tools) to see these kinds of errors. Here's something simpler: go [here](https://alpha.editor.p5js.org/) and copy your P5.js code into it, changing your variable name